# Relation between two definitions of locally closed maps

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following two conditions on a map $X\overset{f}{\to}Y$ between topological spaces.

1. There is a family of opens $(V_i)$ in $Y$ such that $(f^{-1}V_i)$ is an open cover of $X$ and each $f^{-1}V_i\to V_i$ is closed.
2. There's an open cover $(U_i)$ of $X$ such that the restrictions $U_i\to Y$ take closed subsets *of* $Y$ to closed subsets of $Y$.

When $f$ is a subspace inclusion the first condition gives the usual definition of a locally closed subspace. The second condition appears in a paper.

How are these conditions related?